# Stop div scrolling once it reaches another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I currently have a div which stays fixed and follows the user down as they scroll until it reaches a certain point. I can easily make it stop at a fixed pixel position as I have done in the below example, but because I'm a jQuery idiot I have no idea how to make it stop at a div instead.

Here's what I've used so far:

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
     var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

$window.scroll(function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
        });
    } else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
    }
});
};

$('#one').followTo(400);
```

Here's the example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1445/)

The reason I want it to stop once it reaches a second div is because with the fluid layout I'm using, the second div will be sitting at different points depending on the browser size. Defining a specific point for it to stop at won't work. Anyone got any ideas as to how I can get this to do what I want? Alternatively, is it possible for the fixed div to stop scrolling once it reaches a percentage of the way down? I've looked around but haven't found anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw),
        $bumper = $(elem),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#one').followTo('#two');
```

EDIT: about your request to not scroll until a certain point, just replace this:

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
```

with this:

```
if ($window.scrollTop() <= (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
```

Comment: Good lord, it works! Now to go and figure out why it works. MicronXD, you are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you ridiculously much.

Comment: Apologies in advance for being so needy haha. Is it possible to somehow add that particular code to something similar to this - http://jsfiddle.net/cpL69/13/ - as in, the div doesn't start scrolling until it is reached and then finishes at the second div as it did in your example?

Comment: added it to the end of the answer. NP... this is what I spend all day doing... yet, somehow I still get pleasure out of earning "meaningless internet points" for doing more of it. It could be more efficient, but I'm busy atm. I'll tighten it up later for you.

Comment: eh... I couldn't resist. http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1470/ **disclaimer:** I hate using flags, so instead of an "isAlreadyPositionFixed" flag, I'm updating the variable `setPosition` to point to `over` or `under` which each contain only the code to switch from the current state to the alternate state. The starting point you posted was doing a lot of work for every scroll event that fired. This will do quite a bit less (just a comparison operation in most cases, and css property update only when necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by MicronXD's fiddle, but written to be more flexible when the DOM is getting pushed around a lot on document load (or other reasons), here's another similar solution I developed for my own usage:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  followTo: function (elem, marginTop) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $initialOffset = $this.offset().top;
    setPosition = function() {
      if ( $(window).scrollTop() > $initialOffset ) {
        if ( elem.offset().top > ( $(window).scrollTop() + $this.outerHeight() + marginTop ) ) {
          $this.css({ position: 'fixed', top: marginTop });
        }
        if ( elem.offset().top <= ( $(window).scrollTop() + $this.outerHeight() + marginTop ) ) {
          $this.css({ position: 'absolute', top: elem.offset().top - $this.outerHeight() });
        }
      }
      if ( $(window).scrollTop() <= $initialOffset ) {
        $this.css({ position: 'relative', top: 0 });
      }
    }
    $(window).resize( function(){ setPosition(); });
    $(window).scroll( function(){ setPosition(); });
  }
});
```

Then you can run the function as such:

```
$('#div-to-move').followTo( $('#div-to-stop-at'), 60);
```

60 is the optional margin you want the floating element to have from the top of the screen when in position: fixed, expressed in pixels.