# Scroll divs over each other on pagescroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML-page with several DIVs and a function named 'fullscreenCSS' wich takes care of the DIVs being fullscreen.

When I scroll using the scrollbar, I want the current DIV to stay at its position (if  scrolled to the end of that DIV) and the next one slides over it. I think the current DIV temporarily got to have a position 'absolute' or 'fixed' untill the next one has reached the top of the screen. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

A first attempt can be seen on: http://www.84media.nl/project/couch/

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989695/stop-div-scrolling-once-it-reaches-another-div/10990181#10990181

Comment: Here was the latest version http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1470/ It's pretty much the opposite of what you want. You can likely toy with the conditionals and end up with what you're looking for.

Comment: I updated the js fiddle to do what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How's this look?

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/2227/

Comment: Thnx! That looks good, MicronXD! I updated the test-site: http://84media.nl/project/couch2/

I've added some dummy text into the first DIV. The content is longer compared to the DIV, is it possible to first scroll through this content before the second one scrolls over it?

Comment: Oh and one more thing: unfortunately, position:fixed, wont work on an ipad. Searched for a workaround but not found yet, I will keep searching!

Comment: Unfortunately, I havent found a solution for ipad yet. Also, I'v tried to fade the upcoming DIV (with inview, check if next div is in the viewport). It (fading) works for the first one, but not for the rest of the DIV's. What possible solutions are there? http://84media.nl/project/couch2/ (same code in Fiddle didnt work, http://jsfiddle.net/d6rKn/13/)