# Can't Get HTML/PHP/JavaScript Slideshow Code Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn multiple languages here and I can't seem to get this right. I've searched many sites but haven't found any examples to accomplish this specific task.

On my web server I have a virtual directory that points to a photo repository. I add photos to this folder regularly.

I want the webpage to show the photos in a random order. Also, I don't want to specifically list the photos in the code. I've gotten it working in a basic way with this php code:

```
<?php

$images = glob("*.jpg");

$imgs = '';

foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

shuffle($imgs);

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
echo "<img src='$img' width=\"100%\" /> ";
}
?>
```

This code shows all of the pictures in a folder at full width one after another vertically.

What I'd like to do is remake this so that **the images slide upward over the previous image while you scroll down.**

Then when the image reaches the top of the window it would have a static position and the next image would begin sliding up on top of it.

I can't figure out if this technique is done with php, jquery, css or what?

I'm too ignorant to all of these languages but I'm trying to get the hang of it!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the images slide upward over the previous image while you scroll down." Is this something you've seen elsewhere> If so, please post a link as an example.

Comment: The page linked by @ramirio shows a perfect example of the effect I'd like to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

A [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo1agjLe/) that I forked from another similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12095085/1405326):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <img id="one" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports" />
    <img id="two" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/animals" />
    <img id="three" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food" />
    <img id="four" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature" />
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#one, #two, #three, #four {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position:absolute;
}

#one   { top:0px; }
#two   { top:100%; }
#three { top:200%; }
#four  { top:300%; }
```

**JS (using jQuery)**

```
(function(window){
$.fn.stopAtTop= function () {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window),
        thisPos = $this.offset().top,
        //thisPreservedTop = $this.css("top"),
        setPosition,
        under,
        over;

    under = function(){
        if ($window.scrollTop() < thisPos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: ""
            });
            setPosition = over;
        }
    };

    over = function(){
        if (!($window.scrollTop() < thisPos)){
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
            setPosition = under;
        }
    };

    setPosition = over;

    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });

    $window.scroll(function(){setPosition();});
    setPosition();
};
})(window);

$('#one').stopAtTop();
$('#two').stopAtTop();
$('#three').stopAtTop();
$('#four').stopAtTop();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is exactly the effect I'm going for but I'm not sure how to make this work with the PHP code I have. I don't want to have to specifically list all of the images in the code.

Comment: @StodgyWaif your original code lists the images already - `foreach ($imgs as $img){ echo "<img src='$img' width=\"100%\" /> "; }`. That bit will replace the `<img .. />` elements in @ramirio's HTML section.

Comment: You can give them a class instead of an ID (`<img class="my_imgs" src=.." />`) and refer to that with jQuery (`$(".my_imgs").stopAtTop();`).

Comment: Thanks @DACrosby. I haven't figured out how to implement the JS portion. Is this supposed to be inside of the foreach loop?

Comment: @StodgyWaif The `foreach` I mentioned replaces the 2nd `foreach` in your original post. The `jQuery` piece I mentioned would replace `$('#one').stopAtTop(); ... $('#four').stopAtTop();` at the end of your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

- use HTML to structure ( put images in divs )
- use CSS to style them ( in the middle of the page,  padding n stuff)
- use javascript(jquery) to add "dynamics", there is something link on scroll (to google)
  and attach this function to the window, now this will allow you to specify
  what to do with the elements when scrolling ( select your divs and either hide[function] previous and slideup[function] the next )

Note: just google the functions, hope you learn something good from it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I've got a little better grasp on CSS and DIV's now but I still haven't figured out the javascript.